# counterexample about sets of limit points

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, and $A,B \subseteq X$.

I know that $(A ∪ B)'$ may not be contained in $(A' ∪ B')$.
But I don't know a specific example that show the above statement.

Please let me know the example

Comment: Here, "$\ '\ $" denotes the limit points of a set, rather than the complement of a set?

Comment: oh......I omit the explanation about that....
I use ' to denote the set of limit points...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two sets are indeed equal: If $x$ is neither a limit point of $A$ nor a limit point of $B$, then there is a neighborhood $U$ not containing any point from $A$ distinct from $x$ and there is a neighborhood $V$ not containing any point from $B$ distinct from $x$. The intersection $U\cap V$ contains no point from $A\cup B$ except for $x$ itself, hence $x$ is not a limit point of $A\cup B$. This shows that $(A ∪ B)'\subseteq (A' ∪ B')$

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

**claim:** $(A\cup B)'= A'\cup B'$

**proof:** Let $x\in (A'\cup B')^c$, so there are two open neighborhoods $U_A$ and $U_B$ of $x$ so that $U_A\cap A=\emptyset$ and $U_B\cap B=\emptyset$. Then $U_A\cap U_B$ is open and doesn't intersect $A\cup B$, thus $x\in ((A\cup B)')^c$. This shows $(A\cup B)'\subseteq A'\cup B'$.

The converse direction is trivial.